# How to direct Webpack config file to centralized dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, dependencies

I often want to bundle a Node package for the browser, but I'm very tired of keeping Webpack configs and all the dependencies in every project directory. It creates enormous bloat, when every project needs a fairly small set of loaders: Mainly Babel, CSS/SASS, *SV and HTML|EJS.

So I tried to write a module called ['bundle-module'](https://github.com/wilson428/bundle-module) that can be globally installed and invoked inside a project to produce a version in a local `dist` subdirectory, which it creates if necessary. I got the module to successfully generate a config file with absolute paths to the inputs and outputs when you pass the desired filenames, like so:

```
npm install -g wilson428/bundle-module

# cd /path/to/myproj
# assume myproj has an index.js with it's own 
# project-specific dependencies in package.json

bundle-module --name=myproj --entry=index.js
```

I thought this was working, but it turns out that, when [using the Webpack API to call the compilation process](https://github.com/wilson428/bundle-module/blob/master/bundle.js#L36), it looks for the loaders in the local `node_modules`, such that I get this error:

```
EntryModuleNotFoundError: Entry module not found:
Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/path/to/myproj'
```

This is precisely what I **don't** want--for every project to need it's own copy of `babel-loader` and every other loader.

So, if I could speak to Webpack in plain language, I would say, "Please, sir or madam, when looking for a `loader`, please look in the directory from which you were called, not the directory into which you're compiling`.

The `bundle-module` package has all the correct loaders and other Webpack modules as dependences (also tried `devDependencies`). I also tried "pre-requiring" `babel-loader`, which didn't help.

How can I get a globally installed Webpack instance to use it's local dependencies instead of the project's dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I fixed this, but I suspect there's a better solution:

In the generated config file, I had to use absolute paths to the loaders pointing to the installed modules in the `bundle-module` directory:

```
loader: path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js')
```

(Curiously, even though the `package.json` in `babel-loader` points to `lib/index.js`, naturally, this only seems to work if the complete path is specified.

I'll leave this unanswered just in case anyone has a more obvious, simpler solution!